# Adding user to session, spring security default login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have set up spring security to intercept correctly and prompt user with custom login page, that then authenticates correctly and adds userdetails to SecurityContextHolder.

Supplementary to that I now want to add my own custom User object added to session whenever login is performed; so the code will look like this:

```
public returnwhat? doMySupplementaryLogin() {

   UserDetails principal = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
   MyUser user = myUserService.getMyUser(principal.getUsername());

   add user to what ?
}
```

Where will this code go? I want the nomral spring authentication to be performed and then the above code will put a MyUser object into session and then send user to the original intercepted url/viewname. I have the strong feeling I am making things more complicated than they need to be ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do make it complicated... :)

What you want is to add a custom authentication provider to spring's normal authentication manager.
So you would configure the authentication manager like this:

```
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="authServiceImpl">
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
      </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>
```

Now you only need to define the authServiceImpl bean inside your spring context. You can either do this through xml or annotations (my prefered way).

```
@Service
public class AuthServiceImpl implements AuthService {
```

You need to implement the AuthService interface. Just implement to methods from the interface - should be pretty straight forward. 
You don't need to put things into the SecurityContextHolder yourself - spring will do that.

What you want is this:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
     return MyUser user = myUserService.getMyUser(username);
}
```

Feel free to ask if you have any further questions.

EDIT:
Or you could just have your UserService class implement the interface - I just did it like this because you didn't provide your UserService class.

Comment: thanks, OK, how do I access MyUser(which implements UserDetails) in a controller ? And "Authservice" is a typo and should be "UserDetailsService" ?

Comment: Woops sorry - not a typo. I actually have another interface on my authserviceimpl. AuthService does extend UserDetailsService tho.

Comment: You can access your MyUser class in your controller like you would with any other spring bean. autowire it or config in your applicationContext.xml

Comment: Like any other spring bean ? But isn't it a session attribute/in the security context ? I am makign progress, how to access the MyUser object from within jsp (to display welcome username for example)?

Comment: You don't have to access the User object at all - you can gain access to the userPrincipal (the UserDetails object you returned in the loadUserByUsername method) though: `${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}` will print out the currently logged in username

Comment: the UserDetails object I returned is an Instanceof MyUser, is it not possible to access the custom getter/fields I decalred on that object ? For example getFirstname(), getSurname()

Comment: Maybe you could use the <security:authentication> tag. you can define a property to show in that tag - i think it should be possible to show any field you declared through that tag - test it please as i have never used it before.

Comment: Thnx fo ryour help, yes I did it like you suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807967/accessing-my-custom-user-object-in-jsp-page-using-spring-3-security/7808346#7808346

Comment: @chzbrgla I have a doubt in `defaultSuccessUrl` we pointed to redirect some other path in spring security java config . Is that possible to add or `set-cookie` before those redirected url executed .., because I am accessing server side code in dffrnt port , my client app is running in diifrnt thats why spring security when redirects any other url, the browser doesnt `set-cookie` manually . I got `anonymusUser` lke in my redirected controller..

Comment: @chzbrgla i posted a question also about that , this is not a right though paste the link like this way but for your reference and understanding perspective i pasted could yu please see ths .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386229/is-it-possible-before-redirecting-to-success-or-failure-url-call-by-spring-secur

Answer (score 2):

or add your own AuthenticationSuccessHandler, for instance this class, i added so that i could store the username and password in session so i could login to other microservices when needed:

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessWithSessionHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler, LogoutSuccessHandler {

    public static final String USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.getSession().removeAttribute(USERNAME);
        request.getSession().removeAttribute(PASSWORD);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        request.getSession().setAttribute(PASSWORD, request.getParameter(PASSWORD));
        request.getSession().setAttribute(USERNAME, request.getParameter(USERNAME));
    }
}
```

and registered it

```
        AuthenticationSuccessWithSessionHandler successHandler = new AuthenticationSuccessWithSessionHandler();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/logout", "/images", "/js").permitAll().antMatchers("/feeds/**")
                .authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .successHandler(successHandler)
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(successHandler).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
```

note the extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler stores the original url and restores it after successfull login.