# Accessing my custom user object in jsp page, using spring 3 security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have implemented `UserDetailsService`, it returns an instance of `MyUser` (which implements `UserDetails`)

```
public MyUser loadUserByUsername(String arg0)
```

Now I want to access my custom getters/fields on `MyUser` in my JSP pages, so far I got this:

```
${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}
```

But that only allows access to a [Principal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html) object. How can I access `MyUser` object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

its easy in the jsp page I added this :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
...
<sec:authentication property="principal.firstname" />
```

Where principal is actually an instance of MyUser, so "firstname" can be any of my custom getters and setters

Answer (score 6):

After analyzing the HTTPSesson, immediately after the successful log in, I found out that there is an attribute named **SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT**. For example, mine custom UserDetails has object named **user**, which has property **firstName**. In JSP, value of this property can be reached with the following:

```
${sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal.user.firstName}
```

Comment: for me '${sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal.email}' worked as I can also see even in '<sec:authentication property="principal.firstname" />'  tag we get 'principal.firstname'

Answer (score 2):

If your `MyUser` object implements `Principal` and you place it in the http session on successful login, you could get it from the session and cast it.

---

You could implement the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` inject your `UserDetailsService` in there and place it in the session.

Then you could inject your `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` into the `UsernamePasswordauthenticationFilter` which handles the `<form-login>` element.

If you give me details about your security context config I could give you more details.

Comment: I agree 100%, how do I "place it in the http session on successful login, you could get it from the session and cast it."

Comment: @NimChimpsky paste some relevant parts of your security config please. I'll edit my answer with a bit more detail.

Comment: thnx for your help, I have the soliution, will post it.