# How to display current logged-in user's information in all templates including view managed by WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in Spring Security application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Security and Thymeleaf template. I am trying to display the logged-in user's first name and last name in a template when the controller is managed by a subclass of WebConfigurerAdapter.

So, say my WebConfigurerAdapter subclass looks like this

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
        registry.addViewController("/some-logged-in-page").setViewName("some-logged-in-page");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");

    }
    ....
}
```

My User entity class looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;



    @Column(name="first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    ...
}
```

In my template, I have tried using code like

```
<div sec:authentication="firstName"></div>
```

But it didn't work.

I know it is possible to use a ControllerAdvise as follows:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CurrentUserControllerAdvice {
    @ModelAttribute("currentUser")
    public UserDetails getCurrentUser(Authentication authentication) {
        return (authentication == null) ? null : (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    }
}
```

and then access the details in the template using code like:

```
<span th:text ="${currentUser.getUser().getFirstName()}"></span>
```

But this doesn't work with any view controller registered with my class MvcConfig. Rather I will need to make sure each of my controllers are separate classes.

So, could someone kindly point me to a way to automatically insert the logged-in user details to my view, e.g. some-logged-in-page.html in this example? Thanks

Comment: How about adding the user details in a Cookie which will be accessible to every webpage within the domain?

Comment: use spring security taglib... considering you are using thymeleaf as template refer this : http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar. Thanks for the suggestion. I suppose I could somehow set the data in a cookie and read it via JavaScript, but I believe there ought to be a decent way to access the same data server-side. In PHP for example we could set the data in $_SESSION and access it in any view potentially.

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan. Thanks as well. I tried using the sec:authentication tag, but I couldn't figure out a way to fetch the information I need. Perhaps you could write an answer showing how you can get custom information like firstName in my example? Thanks

Comment: SO already has an answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807967/accessing-my-custom-user-object-in-jsp-page-using-spring-3-security

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's quite easy to accomplish this, thanks to a hint from Balaji Krishnan.

Basically, I had to add the Thymeleaf Spring Security integration module to my build.gradle file as follows:

```
compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3")
```

Then in my template I just used the following markup:

```
<span th:text ="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getUser().getFirstName()}"></span>
```

Answer (score 17):

When using Spring Security 4 and Thymeleaf 3:

```
<span th:text="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getUsername()}"></span>
```

Comment: explain more about your answer

Answer (score 9):

When using Spring boot 2.2.1.

For the maven, Add these lines to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In the thymeleaf

```
<span th:text="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getUsername()}"></span>
<span th:text="${#authentication.getPrincipal().authorities}"></span>
```

Answer (score 4):

This construct is working for me (spring boot 1.5 and 2.0/thymeleaf 3):
It is documented here (bottom of the page) [Thymeleaf + Spring Security integration basics](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html)

```
Logged user: <span sec:authentication="name">Bob</span>
```

Don´t forget to include the sec tag in the html section of your view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
</head>
<body>
```

I hope this helps!
Have a nice day!
Thomas

Comment: do you know of a way to do so with the user's role? like `<span sec:authentication="role">Bob</span>`

Comment: Sure. Just use this: `<span sec:authentication="principal.authorities">[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]</span>` that should do the trick. Here are some hints to find: [spring security thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-thymeleaf). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As @B378 said, When using Spring Security 4 and Thymeleaf 3: you have to use following.

```
<span th:text="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getUsername()}"></span>
```

Because spring security uses UserDetails internally. And UserDetails contains one function called getUsername().

Answer (score 1):

For me, When using Spring boot 2.1.2 I need to use the following

```
<span th:text="${#authentication.getPrincipal()}"></span> <!-- No ".getUsername()"-->
```

With thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5

Answer (score 0):

This page was useful. Thanks for all the replies. 
Please note that if you are using the latest Spring Boot i.e. version `2.1.0` then you need to use the following: `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5`

[LINK](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes)

Answer (score 0):

For thymleaf 4 and above you have to modify some classes in order to get the info. Heres how you can do that:

First, add the getter of your user `getUser(){return this.user;}` in the UserDetails class and then push that object in the UserDetailsService object. Without these changes, thymleaf will not parse your HTML file.

Then you can get the info as follows:

`<span sec:authentication="principal.user.name">`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check if a user is authenticated before trying to print his detais

```
<th:block th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
                    <span>Hello</span>
                    <span th:text="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getFullName()}"></span>
                </th:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

On 2023-March, to display username from either local or social login(like Facebook), I took this method: (when I'm using)

- spring boot version: 3.0.4
- related tech: Maven and Lombok

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

html top

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
```

html body

```
<h3 th:inline="text">
    user: <span sec:authentication="name">not found</span>
</h3>
```

bean class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomOAuth2User implements OAuth2User {

    private OAuth2User oAuth2User;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return oAuth2User.getAttribute("name");
    }
}
```

Part of rendered view page:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've this configuration with **Thymeleaf 3.1.2**, **Sprig Boot 3.1.3** and **Spring Security 6.0.11** (**Java 17**):

Spring Boot:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Thymeleaf for Spring Security:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

HTML Namespace:

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
```

HTML Authenticated user, **option 1**:

```
<span sec:authentication="principal.firstName"></span>
```

HTML Authenticated user, **option 2**:

```
<p th:text="${#authentication.principal.fisrtName}"></p>
```

Object UserLogin:

```
public class UsuarioLogin implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private Integer cve;
   private String name;
   private String firstName;
   private Perfil perfil;
```

Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security