# Avoid to get user informations inside every method/controller Spring Boot

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, session-variables, principal

I'm using `Spring Boot`, and I want to show inside my `navbar` the name and surname of the logged user.

To do that I have to call the principal inside every method of each controller and then I have to add the information to the model.
I think there is a better way to do that. I think about the `session attribute`. Is it correct?

So my question is: Is the session attribute the best choice? 
If yes How can I do it?

Comment: here is proposed solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090329/how-to-display-current-logged-in-users-information-in-all-templates-including-v

Comment: what is your template engine and security framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something along these lines directly in your jsp:
`<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<security:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    authenticated as <security:authentication property="principal.username" /> 
</security:authorize>`
Taken from [baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security)

Answer (score -1):

here is link to proposed solution using [ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)

[How to display current logged-in user's information in all templates including view managed by WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in Spring Security application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090329/how-to-display-current-logged-in-users-information-in-all-templates-including-v)