# Thymeleaf - Getting full name of authenticated user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

According to thymeleaf security [page](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html) I can get the logged username and roles as below:

```
Logged user: <span sec:authentication="name">Bob</span>
Roles: <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities">[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]</span>
```

I have a web application where authentication is done through active directory using `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` as below:

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(adDomain,
            adUrl);
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);  

    return provider;
}
```

Then after the user logged in I have a header page that I use in all my pages with the above `sec:authentication="name"` thymeleaf tag to show the username, but I wanted to see if there's a way to show the full name instead.

Solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092065/808891) is not working for me:

I'm using: `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5`

and using: `<span th:text ="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getUser().getFirstName()}"></span>`

Is giving me: `Method getUser() cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl`

It seems this information comes from: `org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl` and there just a few options are, like the username, but not the rest of the information an AD can have.

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092065/643500?

Comment: `<span th:text ="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getUser().getFirstName()}"></span>` is not working for me. I'm using `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved my issue:

**First**

I added to the provider an `UserDetailsContextMapper` with `org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPersonContextMapper` as below:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
  ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(adDomain, adUrl);
  provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
  provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);          
  provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper());  <---

  return provider;
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
  return new LdapUserDetailsMapper() {
      @Override
      public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
          InetOrgPersonContextMapper personContextMapper = new InetOrgPersonContextMapper();
          return personContextMapper.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);                  
      }           
  };
}
```

**Second**

Then in my header page I added:

```
<span th:text ="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getDisplayName()}"></span>
```

To display the full name.

With this approach you also have access to show all other AD related fields such as:

```
<span th:text ="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getMail()}"></span>
<span th:text ="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getTelephoneNumber()}"></span>
<span th:text ="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getRoomNumber()}"></span>
```

Comment: Hi I tried the same approach that you mentioned. for me UI is broken and the values are not getting displayed. Which version of Springboot, Spring security and thymeleaf are you using?