# Unable to Display Spring Boot Model Data in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hi I am currently working on a Spring Boot Web Application which provides a Project Management Dashboard for Authenticated Users. The app currently consists of 3 main entity classes: User, Role and Project. Both Role and Project have a ManyToMany relationship with the class User. I am using Thymeleaf to display object data within my HTML template but it does not seem to pull my data correctly from my controller.

Whenever, I call all user details and match the current user to the data row **it works**:

```
<div th:each="allUser:${allUsers}">
               <div th:if="${#authentication.getName() == allUser.username}">
                <span class="d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small" th:text="${allUser.firstName}"></span>
                <span class="mr-4 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small" th:text="${allUser.lastName}"></span>
                </div>
               </div>
```

However, when getting the current user in my controller **it doesn't to work**:

```
<div th:each="user:${users}">
               <div th:if="${#authentication.getName() == user.username}">
                <span class="d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small" th:text="${user.firstName}"></span>
                <span class="mr-4 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small" th:text="${user.lastName}"></span>
                </div>
               </div>
```

Additionally, I am trying to display project information for projects assigned to the current user but that also does not print anything to the dashboard:

```
<tr th:each="project:${projects}">
                      <td th:text="${project.pxprojectname}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${project.initialpendingid}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${project.currentpendingid}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${project.completionstatus}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${project.manager}"></td>
                      </tr>
```

My code can be found below:

**User Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pxuser")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "tabid")
    private int tabid;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "pxuser_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tabid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "auth_role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "pxassignment", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usertabid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pxprojectid"))
    private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {

    }

    public User(User user) {
        this.tabid = user.getTabid();
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.firstName = user.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = user.getLastName();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.active = user.isActive();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
        this.projects = user.getProjects();
    }

    public int getTabid() {
        return tabid;
    }

    public void setTabid(int tabid) {
        this.tabid = tabid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Set<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(Set<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

}
```

**Project Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pxproject")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "pxprojectid")
    private String pxprojectid;

    @Column(name = "pxprojectname")
    private String pxprojectname;

    @Column(name = "servername")
    private String servername;

    @Column(name = "initialpendingid")
    private int initialpendingid;

    @Column(name = "currentpendingid")
    private int currentpendingid;

    @Column(name = "completionstatus")
    private String completionstatus;

    @Column(name = "isactive")
    private boolean isactive;

    @Column(name = "sfengagementid")
    private String sfengagementid;

    @Column(name = "manager")
    private String manager;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
    private Set<User> user = new HashSet<>();


    public Project() {
    }

    public Project(String pxprojectid, String pxprojectname, String servername, int initialpendingid, int currentpendingid, String completionstatus, boolean isactive, String sfengagementid, String manager, Set<User> users) {

        this.pxprojectid = pxprojectid;
        this.pxprojectname = pxprojectname;
        this.servername = servername;
        this.initialpendingid = initialpendingid;
        this.currentpendingid = currentpendingid;
        this.completionstatus = completionstatus;
        this.isactive = isactive;
        this.sfengagementid = sfengagementid;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.user = user;

    }

    public String getPxprojectid() {
        return pxprojectid;
    }

    public void setPxprojectid(String pxprojectid) {
        this.pxprojectid = pxprojectid;
    }

    public String getPxprojectname() {
        return pxprojectname;
    }

    public void setPxprojectname(String pxprojectname) {
        this.pxprojectname = pxprojectname;
    }

    public String getServername() {
        return servername;
    }

    public void setServername(String servername) {
        this.servername = servername;
    }

    public int getInitialpendingid() {
        return initialpendingid;
    }

    public void setInitialpendingid(int initialpendingid) {
        this.initialpendingid = initialpendingid;
    }

    public int getCurrentpendingid() {
        return currentpendingid;
    }

    public void setCurrentpendingid(int currentpendingid) {
        this.currentpendingid = currentpendingid;
    }

    public String getCompletionstatus() {
        return completionstatus;
    }

    public void setCompletionstatus(String completionstatus) {
        this.completionstatus = completionstatus;
    }

    public boolean isIsactive() {
        return isactive;
    }

    public void setIsactive(boolean isactive) {
        this.isactive = isactive;
    }

    public String getSfEngagementid() {
        return sfengagementid;
    }

    public void setSfEngagementid(String sfengagementid) {
        this.sfengagementid = sfengagementid;
    }

    public String getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public void setManager(String manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public Set<User> getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Set<User> user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

**Role Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pxrole")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "auth_role_id")
    private int auth_role_id;

    @Column(name = "role_name")
    private String role_name;

    @Column(name = "role_desc")
    private String role_desc;

    public Role() {

    }

    public int getAuth_role_id() {
        return auth_role_id;
    }

    public void setAuth_role_id(int auth_role_id) {
        this.auth_role_id = auth_role_id;
    }

    public String getRole_name() {
        return role_name;
    }

    public void setRole_name(String role_name) {
        this.role_name = role_name;
    }

    public String getRole_desc() {
        return role_desc;
    }

    public void setRole_desc(String role_desc) {
        this.role_desc = role_desc;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

     @Autowired 
     ProjectRepository projectRepository;

     @Autowired 
     ProjectService projectService;

     @Autowired 
     UserRepository userRepository;

     @Autowired 
     CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;


    @GetMapping("/")
        public String index() {
            return "index";
        }


    @GetMapping("/dashboard")
    public String dashboard(Model model, String currentUser) {  


        List<Project> projectList = projectRepository.findByUser_Username(currentUser);

        List<User> userList = customUserDetailsService.getAllUsersDetails();

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(currentUser);

        model.addAttribute("projects", projectList);
        model.addAttribute("allUsers", userList);
        model.addAttribute("users", user);

        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String admin() {
        return "admin";
    }

     // Login form
    @GetMapping("/login")
        public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/logout")
    public String logout() {
    return "login?logout";
}

    @GetMapping("/dashboard/projects")
    public String projects() {
        return "projects";
    }

    @GetMapping("/error")
    public String error() {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

**User Repository**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{
    public User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**Project Repository**

```
public interface ProjectRepository  extends JpaRepository<Project, Integer>{
    List<Project> findByUser_Username(String username);
}
```

**Custom User Details Service**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException{

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);


        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }       
        return new CustomUserDetails (user);
    }   
    public List<User> getAllUsersDetails(){     
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Project Service**

```
@Service
public class ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    //Return List of All Projects
    public List<Project> getProjects(){
        return projectRepository.findAll();

        }

    //Return List of Projects by Username
    public List<Project> getProjectsByUserUsername(String username){
        return projectRepository.findByUser_Username(username);
    }   
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! 
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller for the GetMapping("/dashboard") currentUser variable holds the value null,

hence `User user = userRepository.findByUsername(currentUser)`;
-> outputs the optional object.

`List<Project> projectList = projectRepository.findByUser_Username(currentUser);`
-> outputs the emptyList.
therefore unable to display the data.

by using the Authentication or Principle object we can take out the current logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

you have traversed `users` like list `<div th:each="user:${users}">` but from the controller, you passed it as a single object.

```
User user = userRepository.findByUsername(currentUser);

        model.addAttribute("users", user);
```

either remove the loop from `html` or pass a list from the controller.

Comment: I have tried removing <div th:each="user:${users}">, but that doesn't seem to work. As mentioned here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092065/13237132), using "${#authentication.getPrincipal().getUser().getFirstName()}" actually work, however, I am still unable to call my user's project objects. Any ideas? Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

For beginners
if you want to display model object with text in thymeleaf :

```
< th:text=" 'Hi' + ${obj}">
```