# Using jdbc-user-service inside user-service-ref

Tags: java, session, authentication, spring-security

I am using spring security and for database based authentication I used following configuration and its working fine

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <authentication-provider>
     <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
      users-by-username-query="SELECT ...... U.email_address=?"
      authorities-by-username-query="SELECT ... U.email_address=?">
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

now I wanted to add extra info to the session and came across [Adding user to session, spring security default login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806086/adding-user-to-session-spring-security-default-login), I tried it and now I have a problem.

XML says I cant use user-service-ref and jdbc-user-service combined. Is there a way to sort it out or else what I have to do if I have to use user-service-ref tag only to authenticate users? What can be the other way to add extra info say a whole Users object to the session.?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have deleted the jdb-user-service tag and now using only user-service-ref tag in authentication-provider like
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"/>

and authentication is working fine.

Now what I want is to return custom user details instead of org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User in my customUserDeatilsService but I dont know how to do it, 

Please help me in it if there is anything I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching and experimenting I was able to do it like this.

1. Make a new service say MyUserService that will implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` and has annotation `@Service`. UserDetailsService only has one method `loadUserByUserName`. Implementation of this method will be in MyUserService. It will look like this.

   @Service
   public class MyUserService implements UserDetailsService {

   ```
   @Override
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String arg0)
           throws UsernameNotFoundException {

       MyUser user=new MyUser();
       /*get details of user and authorities from database whose username is   
               arg0 and place them in user instance */
       return user;
   }

   }
   ```
2. MyUser is also a new class that implements `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` and all its methods are implemented inside MyUser class. It will look like this.

   ```
   public class MyUser implements UserDetails {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   /*All the variables their getter setters that you wish to store in session. And    
      implementation of all the methods of UserDetails go here.*/

    }
   ```
3. Define a bean like this
   `<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="org.aurora.timeexpense.service.MyUserService"/>`

Where `org.aurora.timeexpense.service.MyUserService` is the path of my defined service that implements UserDetailsService.

4.And Spring Security Configuration will go like this
 `<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">`
       `<authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">`
        `</authentication-provider>`
   `</authentication-manager>`

You are good to go.